# how can i get this js game in a html

Tags: javascript, html

hi i have made this "rock, paper and scissors" game in javascript and I want to get it showed on a html but I can't figure out how

```
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
} console.log("Computer: " + computerChoice);
var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
if(choice1 === choice2) {
        return 'The result is a tie!';
}

else if(choice1 === "rock")

    {if (choice2 === "scissors") { 
         return 'rock wins';
    }
    else{
        return 'paper wins'
    }
}
    else if (choice1 === "paper")
    {if (choice2 === "rock")
    {return 'paper wins'}
    else{return 'scissors win'}
    }

    else if (choice1 === "scissors")
    {if (choice2 === "paper")
    {return 'scissors win'}
    else {return 'rock win'}
    }
};
compare(userChoice, computerChoice)
```

I know this may sound pretty newbie. But plzz answer

Comment: wrap it in `<script></script>`: http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/incorporate

Comment: You mean show something more graphic or just open a page and see the script run? If it's the later then ^

Comment: i want the stuff I the console log to be showed

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but as you work on this consider what the user will enter. Right now they could enter `fdhajksfh` and the game would still play. There's no form validation. So you need to check that if they enter anything besides rock/paper/scissors they get a message to that only those responses are allowed.

Comment: @ismager78 Did an answer solved your question ? Please, give us any feed back or validation by click on the green tick.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need a `<form>` tag, an `<input type="text">` tag and a submit button. After that, you'll also need some `<span>` tags to receive the computer choice value and the result.

Then some fixes here and there in the JS code (details in the snippets).

Here is a little example.

Note :

- I used the jQuery library to keep it simple,
- You'll need some validation in case someone enter a number or any other thing but paper/rock/scissors,
- Maybe if the user type "help" or any other thing you could print the game rules ?

```js
// lets fire our function when the form is submited
$('#lets_rock_paper_scissors').submit(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); // prevent the page reload
  
  var userChoice = $('#user_choice').val(); // get the value of the input by ID
  var computerChoice = Math.random();
  
  if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
  } else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
  } else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
  } 
  
  // populate the span tag with the computer choice
  $('#computer_choice').html("Computer: " + computerChoice);

  // populate the span tag with the compare() function result
  $('#result').html(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));
});

function compare(choice1, choice2) {
  if(choice1 === choice2) {
     return 'The result is a tie!';
  } else if(choice1 === "rock") {
    if (choice2 === "scissors") { 
      return 'rock wins';
    } else {
      return 'paper wins';
    }
  } else if (choice1 === "paper") {
    if (choice2 === "rock") {
      return 'paper wins';
    } else {
      return 'scissors win';
    }
  } else if (choice1 === "scissors") {
    if (choice2 === "paper") {
      return 'scissors win';
    } else {
      return 'rock win';
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h3>Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?</h3>

<form id="lets_rock_paper_scissors">
  <input type="text" id="user_choice" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>

<p><span id="computer_choice"></span></p>

<p><span id="result"></span></p>
```

Hope it helps. Have fun. ; )

Answer (score 0):

You can try with adding  tags between your code and then save your code as a html file.

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing much and needs improving (meaning you can type a wrong word and get no winner/loser). But that is for you. Just copy the code and put it in a text document from notepad or notepad++, save it as whatevernameyouwant.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script> 

var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

computerChoice = computerChoice < 0.34 ? "rock" : computerChoice < 0.67 ? "paper" : "scissors";

var compare = function(choice1, choice2) {
    if(choice1 === choice2) {
        return 'The result is a tie!';
    }else if(choice1 === "rock"){
        if (choice2 === "scissors") { 
            return 'You win with rock';
        }else{
            return 'Computer wins with scissors';
        }
    }else if (choice1 === "paper"){
        if (choice2 === "rock"){
            return 'You win with paper';
        }else{
            return 'Computer wins with rock'}
    }else if(choice1 === "scissors"){
        if (choice2 === "paper"){
            return 'You win with scissors';
        }else{
            return 'Computer wins with paper';
        }
    }
};

alert(compare(userChoice, computerChoice));


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with only minimal `HTML` added. As others have mentioned, you are doing no input validation so this program will accept whatever string it is given.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Rock, Paper, Scissors</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var playAgain = false;
        var comp_Win = 0;
        var user_Win = 0;
        do{

            var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?\n");

            var maximum = 3;
            var minimum = 1;
            var computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;

            if (computerChoice == 1) {
                computerChoice = "rock";
            } else if(computerChoice == 2) {
                computerChoice = "paper";
            } else if (computerChoice == 3){
                computerChoice = "scissors";
            }


            function compare(userChoice, choice2) {
                if(userChoice === choice2) {
                    return 'The result is a tie!';
                } else if(userChoice === "rock"){
                    if (choice2 === "scissors") {
                        user_Win++;
                        return 'You win!'

                    }
                    else{
                        comp_Win++;
                        return 'Computer Wins.'
                    }
                }
                else if (userChoice === "paper"){
                    if (choice2 === "rock"){
                        user_Win++;
                        return 'You Win!'
                    }
                    else{
                        comp_Win++;
                        return 'Computer Wins.'
                    }
                }

                else if (userChoice === "scissors"){
                    if (choice2 === "paper"){
                        user_Win++;
                        return 'You win!'
                    }
                    else {
                        comp_Win++;
                        return 'Computer Wins.'
                    }
                }
            };
            alert(compare(userChoice, computerChoice)+"\n");


            if (confirm('Play again?')) {
                playAgain=true;
            } else {
                playAgain=false;
            }


        }while(playAgain);

        alert("User: "+user_Win+"\nComputer: "+comp_Win+"\n");
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a version that 'just runs':

```js
var playAgain = false;
  var comp_Win = 0;
  var user_Win = 0;
  do{

   var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?\n");

   var maximum = 3;
   var minimum = 1;
   var computerChoice = Math.floor(Math.random() * (maximum - minimum + 1)) + minimum;

   if (computerChoice == 1) {
    computerChoice = "rock";
   } else if(computerChoice == 2) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
   } else if (computerChoice == 3){
    computerChoice = "scissors";
   }


   function compare(userChoice, choice2) {
    if(userChoice === choice2) {
     return 'The result is a tie!';
    } else if(userChoice === "rock"){
     if (choice2 === "scissors") {
      user_Win++;
      return 'You win!'

     }
     else{
      comp_Win++;
      return 'Computer Wins.'
     }
    }
    else if (userChoice === "paper"){
     if (choice2 === "rock"){
      user_Win++;
      return 'You Win!'
     }
     else{
      comp_Win++;
      return 'Computer Wins.'
     }
    }

    else if (userChoice === "scissors"){
     if (choice2 === "paper"){
      user_Win++;
      return 'You win!'
     }
     else {
      comp_Win++;
      return 'Computer Wins.'
     }
    }
   };
   alert(compare(userChoice, computerChoice)+"\n");


   if (confirm('Play again?')) {
    playAgain=true;
   } else {
    playAgain=false;
   }


  }while(playAgain);

  alert("User: "+user_Win+"\nComputer: "+comp_Win+"\n");
```